# rust vulkan, normals are messed up

Tags: rust, gpu, vulkan, renderdoc

I am trying to render a gltf model with ash (vulkan) in rust.

I sent all my data to the gpu and I am seeing this:

[image]

Naturally my suspicion is that the normal data is wrong. So I checked with renderdoc:

[image]

Those seem ok, maybe the attributes are wrong?

[image]

All those normals seem like they add to 1, should be fine. Maybe my pipeline is wrong?

[image]

Seems like the correct format and binding (I am sending 3 buffers and binding one to binding 0, one to 1 and the last to 2, binding 1 has the normals).

The only thing I find that is weird is, if I go to the vertex input pipeline stage see the buffers:

[image]

This is what the buffer at index 1 shows:

[image]

This does not happen for the buffer at index 0 (positions) which also render properly. So Whatever is causing the normals to show up as hex codes here is likely the cause of the bug. But i have no idea why this is happening. As far as I can see the pipeline and buffer were all set properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You presumably want to use one separate buffer for each vertex attribute (aka non-interleaved vertex buffer, SoA),
but your `VkVertexInputAttributeDescription::offset` values `[0, 12, 24]` is what you would use for one vertex buffer interleaving all attributes (provided that their `binding` values point to one and the same `VkVertexInputBindingDescription`).
e.g.

```c
// Interleaved:
// Buffer 0: |Position: R32G32B32_FLOAT, Normal: R32G32B32_FLOAT, Uv: R32G32B32_FLOAT|, * vertex count
VkVertexInputBindingDescription {
  .binding = 0,
  .stride  = 12 * 3, // 3 `R32G32B32_FLOAT`s !
  .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX
};
// All attributes in the same `binding` == `0`
VkVertexInputAttributeDescription[3] {
  {
    .location = 0,
    .binding  = 0,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 0 // [0, 11] portion
  },
  {
    .location = 1,
    .binding  = 0,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 12 // [12, 23] portion
  },
  {
    .location = 2,
    .binding  = 0,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 24 // [24, 35] portion
  }
};
```

Your `VkVertexInputBindingDescription[1].stride` == `12` tells Vulkan that your vertex buffer `1` uses `12` bytes for each vertex, and your `VkVertexInputAttributeDescription[1].offset` == `12` says the normal value is at offset 12, which is out of bounds.
Same deal with your `VkVertexInputAttributeDescription[2].offset` == `24` overstepping (by a large amount) `VkVertexInputBindingDescription[2].stride` == `12`.

For using one tightly-packed buffer for each vertex attribute, you need to correctly set your `VkVertexInputAttributeDescription[n].offset` values to `0`, which looks something like:

```
// Non-interleaved:
// Buffer 0: |Position: R32G32B32_FLOAT|, * vertex count
// Buffer 1: |Normal: R32G32B32_FLOAT|, * vertex count
// Buffer 2: |Uv: R32G32B32_FLOAT|, * vertex count
VkVertexInputBindingDescription[3] {
  {
    .binding = 0,
    .stride  = 12,
    .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX
  },
  {
    .binding = 1,
    .stride  = 12,
    .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX
  },
  {
    .binding = 2,
    .stride  = 12,
    .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX
  }
};
// Each attribute in its own `binding` == `location`
VkVertexInputAttributeDescription[3] {
  {
    .location = 0,
    .binding  = 0,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 0 // Whole [0, 11]
  },
  {
    .location = 1,
    .binding  = 1,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 0 // Whole [0, 11]
  },
  {
    .location = 2,
    .binding  = 2,
    .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32G32_SFLOAT,
    .offset   = 0 // Whole [0, 11]
  }
};
```

Worth noting is the comment line `// vertex stride 12 less than total data fetched 24` generated by RenderDoc in the Buffer Format section, and [how it does so](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/blob/be674c012b883d51896259011ec6fd77a2067bca/qrenderdoc/Windows/PipelineState/PipelineStateViewer.cpp#L1380-L1387).
It detects when your vertex attribute description oversteps its binding description's stride:

```
if(i + 1 == attrs.size())
{
  // for the last attribute, ensure the total size doesn't overlap stride
  if(attrs[i].byteOffset + cursz > stride && stride > 0)
    return tr("// vertex stride %1 less than total data fetched %2")
        .arg(stride)
        .arg(attrs[i].byteOffset + cursz);
}
```